# Can't add/switch to Microsoft Account from Local Account

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, login, microsoft-account

I had a snafu during Windows setup where I initially created my Windows install using my Microsoft account. However, the install created a user profile name that didn't match older machines which caused lots of  of broken file links etc. To restore my original user and account name I created a new **local** account, then **removed** the original account that was linked to my Microsoft account.

Everything is working with the local account, but I'd like to go back to using a Microsoft Account for logging in and syncing Windows machines and profiles now that my profile is properly named.

However I seem to be unable to do so. I removed the Microsoft account, but I continue to see that user listed in user list:

[image]

The Computer -> User Manager doesn't show the user, nor is there a Profile in `c:\users` on disk or in the User Profiles listed. Notice that there is no option to **Remove** the user from the Family & other people form. There was a Remove option initially and I used that to remove all data, but the result is what's shown in the image above.

With this account there and because it shows with my Microsoft email address, I can't switch to my Microsoft login for the new local account that I'd like to switch. It doesn't have the option to **Switch to Microsoft Account**:

[image]

So, any ideas on what needs to happen to completely remove the original now unused account so that it is no longer visible to Windows?